# Attempt to read property "profile" on null

Tags: php, authentication, eloquent, laravel-9

hello I have 2 databases, namely users and profiles, profiles has a foreign key that is user_id. Then the relationship between the two is one to one.

**this my Profile model here**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Profile extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $table='profile_users';
    protected $fillable = [
        'province','user_id', 'bio','facebook'
    ];

/**
 * Get the user that owns the Profile
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
 */
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class, 'user_id');
}

}
```

**this my User Model here**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

// use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasApiTokens, HasFactory, Notifiable;

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for serialization.
     *
     * @var array<int, string>
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast.
     *
     * @var array<string, string>
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    /**
     * Get the user associated with the User
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOne
     */
    public function profile()
    {

        return $this->hasOne(Profile::class);
    }

}
```

**This is my controller function**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use App\Models\Profile;
class ProfileController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $user=Auth::user(); 
        $id=Auth::id();

        if ($user->profile==null) {

          $profile=Profile::create([
            'province'=>'##',
            'user_id'=>$id,
            'bio'=> "hi ",
            'facebook'=>"https://www.facebook.com"
          ]);
          return view('users.profile')->with('user',$user);

        }
```

the code above produces an error that is Attempt to read property "profile" on null. so how do i solve it?

please help and thanks alot

Comment: i think the problem is that you assign `$profile = Profile::create(...` instead of  `$user->profile = Profile::create(... ` in your controller

Comment: Or that `$user` actually is `null` itself.

Comment: still not work .how can I check in another way?